# Attribute weak extern in Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c

I'm converting the obj-c framework to the Swift one.

I need to convert this line:

```
__attribute__((weak)) extern NSString *sdkVersion = 0;
```

to Swift similar one. Spend a lot of time on google, but didn't find the answer.

Predicting your questions, what I'm trying to achieve... in short words, this global variable is defined in an optional framework. My Swift function should print this version in case if our SDK is linked with that framework.
I know, I can create a wrapper (another objc framework), add necessary getters there, and then link it with the main framework. But may be there is a more simple solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `public weak var sdkVersion:String? = nil` ‍♂️

Comment: @Cy-4AH - The OP's code is specifying weak-linking, your snippet is a weak reference, not the same thing :-(

Comment: @Alex – DDG "Swift weak linking" to see how people do it in Swift (it does not appear to covered in the Swift Programming Language), there are a number of useful looking hits. HTH